# nginx: redirect to docker containers with https enabled

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, docker

I have two containers running in an EC2 instance, the first uses port 4200 and the second 8188. I also have a domain name "my-domaine.com" connected to my EC2 instance.
I'm aiming to reach these containers via the domain and via a secure connection, so I took the following steps.

- Add two different domains to each container called "app1.my-domaine.com" and "app2.my-domaine.com" (each domain will be taken to a different container)
- installed lets encrypt certificate
- installed nginx server on the EC2 instance
- I have added the following configuration to enable https and forward the requests from the domaine name to the containers like this.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-domaine.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  app1.my-domaine.com;
    port_in_redirect on;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domaine.com/fullchain.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domaine.com/privkey.pem";

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200;
    }

    # added this to redirect any path to the container as well
    location ~ ^/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200$1$2;
    }
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  app2.my-domaine.com;
    port_in_redirect on;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domaine.com/fullchain.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domaine.com/privkey.pem";

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8188;
    }

    location ~ ^/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8188$1$2;
    }
}
```

The issue I am encountering is an error message when loading files such as.js,.css, or.json files, despite the fact that I have included this block:

```
location ~ ^/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8188$1$2;
}
```

I am also receiving the default 404 error page from nginx when I add a path to the domain, such as "app1.my-domaine.com/admin" for example.
Do you have any suggestions on how to ensure that all requests, including any path or file, are routed to the appropriate containers?

**UPDATE**
I have changes this

```
location ~ ^/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8188$1$2;
}
```

to this

```
location ~ ^/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8188/$1$2;
}
```

The CSS and JS files are loaded correctly, but there's still one problem. When I go to https://app1.my-domain.com/admin in the browser, it redirects me to 127.0.0.1:4200/admin. This means that nginx is redirecting the request instead of proxying it.

Comment: what should $1 and $2 do? a normal valid proxy_pass is like: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8188;` without a slash on the end

Comment: What is this "redirect" of which you speak? There is no "redirect" in DNS. There is no redirect in your nginx config. You seem to be trying to proxy traffic. Nothing to do with redirection.

Comment: @djdomi $1 and $2 means that any path after the domaine name should be taken as it is and add it to the proxy pass address (example: http://my-domain.com/admin?arg=something ==> http://127.0.0.1:8188/admin?arg=something)

Comment: @symcbean when I write in the browser  https://app1.my-domain.com/ I get the web page of container1 successfully, in this web page I have a couple of links that gets visitor to specific pages (think of it as a website) when I clik on one of this links (contat page for example) I get redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8188/contact instead of app1.my-domain.com/contact

Comment: Again: what redirect? There are no redirects in what you've shown us - only proxying. If you are seeing a 3xx response then its an issue in the service being proxied. You have a comment saying "added this to redirect" - THIS IS NOT A REDIRECT.

Comment: @symcbean I mean that's the issue I'm using only proxy_pass yet I get redirection behavior
the first page gets proxied to the container successfully but when I click on links I get redirected to 127.0.0.1 (in the browser URL field instead of getting `app1.my-domain.com/contact` I get `127.0.0.1:8188/contact`)

Comment: You keep saying "redirect" when there appears to be no redirect. If you can't describe the problem how is someone supposed to understand what you want to achieve? If you don't understand the terminology, how will you understand the responses?

Comment: @symcbean I'm describing the behavior I saw, it might not be the right word technically but this what is really happening, ther is no redirect in the nginx configuration but it is happening in the browser, not sure what word to use to describe going from link to another!

Comment: i think really about, that you need to read [NGINX Reverse Proxy Manual](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) in example a request for example.com/sub/dir/some/where will be passed automaticly to the desition through the proxy, there is no variable required to do so.

Comment: The redirect comes from your backend. Configure it to the correct base URL (the reverse proxy URL).

Comment: And your second proxy block is superfluous, the first one already proxies everything.

Comment: How are your docker networks configured? I would recommend using docker compose and then network mode host